# Why for a point in a given circle to be closest to the origin it must be collinear to center of circle and origin?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, circles, self-learning

Why for a point in a given circle to be the closest to origin, it must be collinear to center of circle and origin?

Comment: Just draw a diagram and think about it!

Comment: Shortest distance between the center of the circle and the origin is a straight line

Comment: I've seen this before when I was teaching a class. The notes glossed over it, so I proved it using the triangle inequality, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Straight line is the shortest way from the center to the origin and if you draw that line, it will intersect the circle. The point of intersection is on that line. If there is another point on the circle that's closer to the origin, it means that there is a shorter way from the origin to the center, which is impossible.

Comment: @MateoHoxhaj +1 to answer: "Straight line is the shortest way from the center to the origin and if you draw that line, it will intersect the circle."  Note that for any *path* taken from center of circle to origin, it will actually consist of two line segments, the first of which has distance equal to the **fixed** radius of the circle.  Therefore, as Vasya indicated, the problem elegantly reduces to minimizing the shortest distance from the center of the circle to the origin, which **must be** a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?  Just think about it!

[image]